# metric property and psd matrix

Tags: matrices, metric-spaces, positive-semidefinite

Let $X$ be a set, and  $d : X × X \to R$ a metric on $X$ 
(which means that verifies : $d(x, y) \geq 0$
,$d(x, y) = 0$ if and only if $x = y$ 
,$d(x, y) = d(y, x)$ 
and $d(x, y) \leq d(x, z) + d(z, y)$),

My question is if the $n$x$n$ matrix defined by $$M_{ij}:=(1-d_{ij})$$with  $d_{ij}=d(x_i,x_j)$ for $x_i$ and $x_j$ in $X$, is a positive semidefinite matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Take $n=2, X=\mathbb R, d(x,y)=|x-y|, x_1=4$ and $x_2=1$. Then $M$ has the eigenvalue $-1$.Therefore $M$ is not positive semidefinite.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If i add one more condition that d(x,y) <= 1 for all x,y in X, is M then positive semidefinite?

Comment: Is there any relation between a metric matrix and a PSD matrix then? There should be something....